# Several domains: centralize them in a single registrar or using multiple registrars?

Tags: domains, management, icann

I have several web projects that I'm starting to develop.
They are 4 different domains, registered in 3 different places.

The 60 days period that the ICANN sets as mandatory "waiting time" (before you move the domains) have passed, and I'm free to move them now, and eventually centralizing them.

I tend to think it would be better for a more comfortable management, however, would there be any reason not to do it, or any pros in keeping them scattered?

Just trying to get some inputs/experiences before I move ahead!

Comment: So your question is: Is there an up-side to making my life far more complicated than it needs to be by requiring me to maintain several URLs, login IDs, payment schedules, payment methods, payment amounts, etc., versus making my life simpler with just one?

Comment: Lol I guess that would be a very valid answer... The situation is so evident I was a bit paranoid.

Comment: Cheers Mate!! Sometimes it takes someone elses point of view to make things clear. I had a friend that wanted to know if there was a module that was like x but more like y in function. I asked him, If you were to code it, how would you do it? He answered. I grinned and said, Well? He had it done in a hour.

Comment: Years ago, when I was a web host, there was no choice but to use Network Solutions. When GoDaddy came around, I transferred many hundreds of domains to GoDaddy. Having one place to go makes life a lot easier. Just choose a quality registrar. I have had good experience with GoDaddy all these years, however, there are others with a different point of view. Take criticisms with salt. Some folks are wound too tight and would not be satisfied with whoever they choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked for a company once who went down this road. It was manageable with a handful of domains, but at one point we held several hundred and it just got to be silly. Sure we had a spreadsheet to tell us what was where, but when it came to ongoing management like renewals (and remembering to charge end-clients for them) it led to more frustration than it was worth.

Ultimately we decided to find one registrar who gave a good balance of price & ease of management. This also meant that whenever we needed to transfer a domain in/out for a client we had the process down pat without having to think about which registrar requires what information &c.

There were a few cases where a separate registrar was required for specific TLDs (like Switzerland & Hong Kong) but at least that was easier to remember than randomly spreading them apart.

Answer (score 3):

I am a hosting provider and domain reseller.  I spend much of my time helping people who have lost track of where their domain is registered and have no idea of the difference between domain registration and site hosting.

As I say to them *having everything in one place will almost certainly help you avoid tears and heartache - trust me on this*.

Find a registrar that has a good control panel, is easy to contact and gives great service.

That is actually me, but I won't self-promote :o)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers about convenience, you may also be able to save money by using a single registrar.

Registrars may have discounts for registering or renewing many domains at the same time.  When you have 100 domains at the same registrar, you may be able to renew all of them at a discount compared to renewing each one individually.

GoDaddy approached me about signing up for their "Pro" service where you pay a yearly fee, but get discounts.   It wasn't worth it for the smaller number of domains I have registered, but with hundreds it could make sense.